# Sorting in python, and empty strings

Tags: python, string, sorting

Hi I'm using the sorted() function in Python to order a bi-dimensionnal array (I want to sort columns just like it can be done in a classic spreadsheet).

In the example below I use itemgetter(0) to sort the grid based on first column's contents.

But sorted returns empty strings before non-empty ones.

```
    >>> import operator
    >>> res = [['charly','male','london'],
    ... ['bob','male','paris'],
    ... ['alice','female','rome'],
    ... ['','unknown','somewhere']]
    >>> sorted(res,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    [['', 'unknown', 'somewhere'], ['alice', 'female', 'rome'], ['bob', 'male', 'paris'], ['charly', 'male', 'london']]
    >>>
```

while I would need it to return this:

```
[['alice', 'female', 'rome'], ['bob', 'male', 'paris'], ['charly', 'male', 'london'], ['', 'unknown', 'somewhere']]
```

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a different key function. One that would work is:

```
sorted(res, key=lambda x: (x[0] == "", x[0].lower()))
```

The key is then a tuple with either 0 (False) or 1 (True) in the first position, where True indicates that the first item in the record is blank. The second position has the name field from your original record. Python will then sort first into groups of non-blank and blank names, and then by name within the non-blank name gorup. (Python will also sort by name within the blank name group, but since the name's blank it's not going to do anything.)

I also took the liberty of making the name sorting case-insensitive by converting them all to lower-case in the key.

Just replacing the blank names with "ZZZZZZ" or something "alphabetically high" is tempting, but fails the first time some joker puts their name as "ZZZZZZZZ" for a test. I guess something like `'\xff' * 100` could work, but it still feels like a hack (also, potential Unicode pitfalls).

Comment: I was about to write this answer exactly; this is the most elegant way to do this. You use a tuple to "promote" your key alphabet without modifying anything you wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a key function, returning the actual value, or 100 'z's if the first element is empty (empty strings evaluate to `False`.

```
sorted(res, key= lambda x: x[0] if x[0] else 'z'*100 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, be it a bit verbose:

```
def cmp_str_emptylast(s1, s2):
    if not s1 or not s2:
        return bool(s2) - bool(s1)

    return cmp(s1, s2)

sorted(res, key=operator.itemgetter(0), cmp=cmp_str_emptylast)
```

Comment: This will only work in python2.X; `cmp=` is foolishly deprecated in favor of `key=`

Comment: @ninjagecko: I had no idea! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -2):

```
key=lambda x: x[0] if x[0] else '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```